# Can you have a guard clause that waits for a storyboard to complete

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, caliburn.micro

I want to define a storyboard that runs for five seconds when a button is pressed:

- Can I put a guard clause on a story board to stop the button from being pressed multiple times?
- **If Not**, What would be a way of handling this without having to reference the animation explicitly in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need the button to be linked to the animation, then I would probably create a TriggerAction (System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerAction) and attach it to the button. The action would then disable the button, kick off the animation and listen for the animation's Completed event before re-enabling the button.

IMHO MVVM is not appropriate in this scenario since all interactions are View related and there is no really good way to inform your ViewModel that the animation is animating. Furthermore the actual animation time is not deterministic, so may have other implications if you are assuming a fixed time.

You may also want to have a look at setting the [HandOffBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.beginstoryboard.handoffbehavior.aspx) of your animation. Depending on what animation you are actually doing, there may be no real penalty if the user were to hammer the button repeatedly. If there is, then use the above suggestion and disable the button.

Comment: That is what I end up thinking myself, the animation is strictly view related and as such there is no real need to add a property to the ViewModel, as I was saying in the comments above, the data is already present, the animation is strictly presentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

- When the button is clicked, start your `Storyboard` and set you `Button.IsEnabled` to false. This will prevent subsequent clicks.
- Handle `Storyboard.Completed` event to re-enable your button.

From an MVVM perspective, the enabled state of your button should be a property of your view-model. You should be able to expose this as a boolean property and bind it to `Button.IsEnabled`. When you launch your storyboard (presumably from code-behind), you can set your button enabled state via a reference to the view model.

Yes, ... in code-behind! This still sufficiently de-couples your view from your view-model and allows unit testing.

Comment: This is a good idea, my only concern is that I don't usally take a reference to the ViewModel in the View and don't really want to do it for one property... If I have to I will but I would like to see other peoples options first.

Comment: @deanvmc fair enough. However, it is worth remembering that while a view-model may have multiple views, a view typically only renders a single view-model type. Hence, referencing a concrete view-model type within a view code-behind rarely causes issues.

Comment: That is very true, I wonder however, If I need to access a ViewModel property on the View for the purpose of only controlling the View (The data is there, the storyboard just simulates it taking time to populate) should the property even belong to the ViewModel, if I took the View off the top, the property would never be considered. I wonder should I just control the whole process (storyboard + guard clause) directly in the code behind, since it is a View Only restriction to hide the button, for the purpose of letting the storyboard run its course, thoughts?